# IE9 checkbox state change form submit back button does not show correct state

Tags: javascript, jquery, checkbox, internet-explorer-9

I have a form with a few checkboxes. Each time I check/uncheck one box form is submitted. Relevant code:

```
$("input[name='checkboxgroup']").bind("click",function(e) {
     e.preventDefault();
...
...
     form.submit();
});
```

However when I click back button on IE9 it shows all my checkboxes still checked( Expected: checkbox last checked before Back button should've been unchecked)

The backend sends data to check/uncheck checkbox whenever page reloads. I have verified that last checkbox clicked before Back button does have "unchecked" state. However, somehow IE9 sets this checkbox as checked.

**Edit**

I did some quick checks:

**Pre**

I have none of the checkboxes checked

I put a break in the Dev tools debugger after `e.preventDefault()` statement...but before `submit()` to check the state being passed to backend.

In Dev tools console I check `$("#checkboxId").attr("checked")` to verify the state as I see

**What I observed**

```
verify $("#checkboxId1").attr("checked") =  undefined ...(expected as the box is not checked) --> 

check this checkbox ---> hits debugger break point ---> 

verify $("#checkboxId1").attr("checked")  is "checked" (as expected) ...but the browser shows checkbox not checked (also expected..preventDefault effect) --> 

request goes to backend --> reloads page --> 

verify $("#checkboxId1").attr("checked") is checked(as expected) --> 

checkbox is now checked (perfect)
```

*...Now the problem:*

Having done the above steps...if I click back button

My expectation: should show unchecked checkbox1

Actual results:  it still shows checked.

> In other browsers: FF, Chrome, Opera, Safari it works per expectations

Any pointers appreciated.

Comment: You have `e.preventDefault();` so the state of the checkbox is not changed by the click. You send data to change the state in the new page loaded after the form is submitted. Why do you expect that state to be carried back to the previous page? This design (stopping default behaviour then using the server and front end script to replicate it) seems seriously flawed.

Comment: @RobG thanks for your comment!!....I have updated my question...hopefully that answers your questions